# how to set the time page refresh without open in browser in php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

> I am using php code for send remainder to send mail
>   how to set the time page refresh without open in browser in php or javascript

Comment: so what has this got to do with java?

Comment: what research have you done for yourself?

Comment: no. i work on php and javascript

Comment: run a cron job for that

Comment: Create a server cron job for sending the mail

Comment: mr. rahul please tell me procedure to create it.

Comment: just google it..

Comment: See procedure below, cheers

Answer (score 0):

### Cron job

Procedure: [See this link here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)

**Syntax of crontab**

The syntax is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 /path/to/command arg1 arg2
```

OR

```
1 2 3 4 5 /root/backup.sh
```

Where,

```
1: Minute (0-59)
2: Hours (0-23)
3: Day (0-31)
4: Month (0-12 [12 == December])
5: Day of the week(0-7 [7 or 0 == sunday])
/path/to/command – Script or command name to schedule
```

Easy to remember format:

```
* * * * * command to be executed
- - - - -
| | | | |
| | | | ----- Day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
| | | ------- Month (1 - 12)
| | --------- Day of month (1 - 31)
| ----------- Hour (0 - 23)
------------- Minute (0 - 59)
```

**Example:**
Run /scripts/phpscript.php at 10 pm on weekdays, enter:

```
0 22 * * 1-5 /scripts/phpscript.php
```

### Scheduled Task

**To create a basic task by using the Windows interface**

1. If Task Scheduler is not open, start Task Scheduler. For more information, see Start Task Scheduler.
2. Find and click the task folder in the console tree that you want to create the task in. For more information about how to create the task in a new task folder, see Create a New Task Folder.
3. In the Actions Pane, click Create Basic Task .
4. Follow the instructions in the Create Basic Task Wizard.

---

Under linux you nedd to create a cron job and if you run windows just create a scheduled task and run your php script

Cheers